# Nuget login errors with Jenkins and Artifactory

Tags: nuget, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Running into an issue with *Nuget*, *Jenkins*, and *Artifactory*. Can't seem to get the *Jenkins* pipeline to recognize the *Nuget* configuration

What is working:

- login to artifactory with the account I'm trying to read with.
- view the repository and artifacts I am trying to access.
- use the nuget command line to access the repository and put in username and password when     prompted.

Now when the same process is put in a *Jenkins* pipeline, I get the following:

"The remote server indicated that the previous request was forbidden.  Please provide credentials for **[https://host.domain/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/repo**"](https://host.domain/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/repo**%22)

Here is how I setup nuget:

```
nuget.exe sources Add -Name Artifactory -Source https://host.domain/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/repo -username <username> -password <password>
```

`nuget.exe setapikey <username>:<password> -Source Artifactory`

Even adding the two lines above result in the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Artifactory repository button "Set Me Up".
This is how to step by step.

Comment: That lead me to the correction path.  With NuGet it appears that you need the hashed password out of the "Set Me Up" option to get things to work.  The actual password will not work in my case.  It may be due to special characters in the password.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had similar error. Nuget.Config was good, everything looked (and was) correctly set up. Turned out nuget was using a CredentialProvider exe from VS2019 which overrode my config settings.
Renamed that exe and everything works as expected.

to check if you are having the same issue, try running:

```
nuget list -Source YourArtifactory -verbosity detailed
```

If it mentions any Credential Providers and their errors - this could be the reason.